# Determining Observation Model for kalman Filter

Tags: matlab, kalman-filter

I am trying to filter tracks from accelerometer and gyroscope in a smartphone using Kalman filter. I walk along a track with known coordinates. The accelerometer and gyroscope reading is captured in a log file, which is then converted to Stride length and orientation. So the basic formula for prediction is

```
delX = Stridelength * cos(Theta)
delY = Stridelength * sin(Theta)
```

and for the update I have coordinates. Prediction phase and Update phase are not one-to-one linked. The prediction phase occurs more than once for each update phase.

for Kalman Filter prediction part, I use,

```
    A = Fk = [1 0; 0 1]; %  the state-transition model
    B = Bk = Stridelength; % control input 
    U = Uk = [cos(Theta); sin(Theta)] % control vector

    p_hat(k) = A * p_hat(k - 1) + B * U;
    P = A * P * A'; % Q process noise is kept null
```

For the Update part, I want to find `Hk` the Observation model stated in this equation. I don't know what should be the Observation model.
`Zk = Hk * p_hat(k)`

Comment: I would do it a different way. You have your accelerometer and gyroscope readings and they should be your measurements for the update state (not a control input for the prediction). Doing so you can easily get the corresponding variances from the datasheet and it will be your R. The conversion from IMU to stride length and orientation will be a part of your update phase. From it you can get the measurement function and the observation matrix (the measurement function will not be linear I assume, so you will need to calculate the Jacobi). Can you please share the conversion fomula?

Comment: The accelerometer and gyroscope reading is continuous and has readings even at rest. Best practices suggest determining step_events (when actual movement happens using thresholds) and compute the length of step (stride length) and orientation.  The formula is here https://github.com/neogeomat/sensor-fusion/blob/master/StepDetection_Acel_smartphone.m